# Insert image from text

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

I have a program that does a custom export of a table, which creates a T-SQL INSERT command with the values hard-coded directly into the INSERT values. I then have an import that simply executes that INSERT command. This has worked great, but now I added an Image column to the table (varbinary) that needs to work as one of the columns as well.

I am looking for a way to convert the images to text, which would also need to be valid so that it works in the INSERT command. I either need VB.NET code to accomplish this or T-SQL; either works.

In summary I am looking for a way to export images stored in the database to text and then using that text as the value to be inserted back into the database.

Comment: What do you mean when you say `convert the images to text`?

Comment: Varbinary can be represented with binary literals/constants: 0xDEADBEEF

Comment: I mean I need to convert an image to an nvarchar aka the literal/constant representation.

Answer (score 0):

So You need to save image as base64 format below is example

Store example

```
string bs64OfBytes = Convert.ToBase64String(byteConvertedImage);
```

byteConvertedImage is byte array of image.

Retrieve example

```
byteConvertedImage = Convert.FromBase64String(Base64stringFromDatabase);
```

byteConvertedImage is byte array of image.

**And another way to convert image to byte and store into image field below is example code.**

```
        Image img = Image.FromFile (path);
        MemoryStream tmpStream = new MemoryStream();
        img.Save (tmpStream, ImageFormat.Png); // change to other format
        tmpStream.Seek (0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        byte[] imgBytes = new byte[MAX_IMG_SIZE];
        tmpStream.Read (imgBytes, 0, MAX_IMG_SIZE);

        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table1(field1) VALUES (value1)";
        IDataParameter par = command.CreateParameter();
        par.ParameterName = "value1";
        par.DbType = DbType.Binary;
        par.Value = imgBytes;
        command.Parameters.Add(par);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery ();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `T-SQL` to do this. Here is the syntax:

```
'0x' + CONVERT(varchar(max), MyImage, 2)
```

Comment: or :  CONVERT(varchar(max), MyImage, 1) , which will prepend the '0x' for you.